How to display Grouped stacked column chart with tooltip for each stack in Android
In my application I am using the Grouped stacked column chart. I am successfully loaded the graph with the sample provided.
 chartView.theme = "grid-light";

        HIOptions options = new HIOptions();

        HITitle title = new HITitle();
        title.setText("Stacked column chart");
        options.setTitle(title);

        HISubtitle subtitle = new HISubtitle();
        subtitle.setText("Plain");
        options.setSubtitle(subtitle);

        //map to list of usagemodel
        List<String> dateFormatList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Float> usageListReg1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Float> usageListReg2 = new ArrayList<>();

        HIXAxis xaxis = new HIXAxis();
        xaxis.setCategories(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Appled", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Bananas")));
        xaxis.setCategories(new ArrayList<>(dateFormatList));
        options.setXAxis(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(xaxis)));

        HIYAxis yaxis = new HIYAxis();
        yaxis.setMin(0);
        yaxis.setTitle(new HITitle());
        yaxis.getTitle().setText("Total fruit consumption");
        yaxis.setStackLabels(new HIStackLabels());
        yaxis.getStackLabels().setEnabled(true);
        yaxis.getStackLabels().setStyle(new HICSSObject());
        yaxis.getStackLabels().getStyle().setFontWeight("bold");
        yaxis.getStackLabels().getStyle().setColor("gray");
        options.setYAxis(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(yaxis)));

        HITooltip tooltip = new HITooltip();
        tooltip.setPointFormat("{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}");
        tooltip.setHeaderFormat("<b>{point.x}</b><br/>");
        tooltip.setBackgroundColor(HIColor.initWithHexValue("eb4034"));
        options.setTooltip(tooltip);

        HIPlotOptions plotoptions = new HIPlotOptions();
        plotoptions.setColumn(new HIColumn());
        plotoptions.getColumn().setStacking("normal");
        options.setPlotOptions(plotoptions);

        HIColumn column1 = new HIColumn();
        column1.setName("John");
        Number[] column1Data = new Number[]{5, 3, 4, 7, 2};
        column1.setData(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(column1Data)));
        column1.setColor(HIColor.initWithHexValue("8B008B"));

        HIColumn column2 = new HIColumn();
        column2.setName("Jane");
        Number[] column2Data = new Number[]{2, 2, 3, 2, 1};
        column2.setData(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(column2Data)));
        column2.setColor(HIColor.initWithHexValue("5F9EA0"));

        options.setSeries(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(column1, column2)));
        chartView.setOptions(options);

Here my question is how to display both values in tooltip. By using the below code, I am able to display the individual data John and Jane separately. like below screenshot.

But I want to display all the 2 stack values in one tooltip John:5 and Jane: 3 line by line
Thanks

Hi, could you please clarify your goal once more? From the screenshot, is this the current result you're getting? And should the final outcome look like the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fpzb1jyn/

Thanks for your response.
No, I want to display all the 3 values in the tooltip, For ex : John 5, Jane 2, Joe 3. All three values in one tooltip like this example
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nr6km382/

Have you tried applying this code via tooltip.setFormatter?
